# how to know which response data is associated with its requested url (in RollingCurl.php)?

Tags: php, curl

I am writing a web application that grabs (*in parallel*) the http response headers from multiple sites (with [RollingCurl](http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/)) then stores it in an array and at the end outputs it in JSON format.

Since some sites do redirects to new locations, $info (array) in “request_callback” function always contains an url ($info[‘url’]) where the requested url was redirected to, and it’s quite expected.
But how to push a requested url into array (@ $info[‘requested_url’]) to know which $info (response data) is associated with its requested url?

```
$urls = array(
 "http://google.com",
 "http://microsoft.com"
    // more urls here
);

$json = array();
$rc = new RollingCurl("request_callback");
$rc->window_size = 20;

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $request = new Request($url);
    $rc->add($request);
}

$rc->execute();
echo json_encode($json);
exit;

function request_callback($response, $info) {
       global $json;
       $json['status'][] = $info;
}
```

// fragment from [RollingCurl.php](http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/source/browse/trunk/RollingCurl.php):

```
// send the return values to the callback function.
$callback = $this->callback;
if (is_callable($callback)){
    $info[‘requested_url’] = **???** // How to get a requested url & push it into $info?
    call_user_func($callback, $output, $info);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your callback function, the $info array should have a 'url' key which is the URL which curl_multi used to make the request.

See the php documentation on [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/curl_getinfo) for the list of things in that array.